# Combining two columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I currently have a csv imported into Jupyter lab. Pandas has been imported, the data frame is 7845 rows x 14 columns. I have two specific columns one named "source_app_packets" and the other is "source_app_packets.1". The two columns are almost identical. The main difference is any data missing from "source_app_packets" is present on "source_app_packets.1" and vice versa. My question is there any way to combine these two?

Comment: please give an example of what you mean by combine

Comment: I would like to take the two columns and turn it into one column. For example in the column "source_app_packets" the value is 39 but in "source_app_packets.1" the value is empty. In my mind the two columns should be the same number.

Comment: what happen if both columns as values and it is different what happen when it is the same if it is not important then the 2 answers below will do the job

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you also import `numpy` you could use something like this, which assumes your data is in `df`.

```py
import numpy as np

# code to import data

# update source_app_packets column
df["source_app_packets"] = np.where(
    df["source_app_packets"].isnull(),
    df["source_app_packets.1"],
    df["source_app_packets"],
)

df.drop(["source_app_packets.1"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. I followed up your lines of code with a drop command to remove the unnecessary column.

Comment: I was going to add code to drop the column but got called away, I've updated the answer with it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df["source_app_packets"].combine_first(df["source_app_packets.1"]
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"source_app_packets":[1, None, 3, None],"source_app_packets.1":[None,2, None, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["source_app_packets"].combine_first(df["source_app_packets.1"])
```

Outputs the following `Series`:

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
Name: source_app_packets, dtype: float
```